# Why does hstack() copy data but hsplit() create a view on it?

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy, why does `hstack()` copy the data from the arrays being stacked:

```
A, B = np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])
C = np.hstack((A,B))
A[0]=99
```

gives for `C`:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

whereas `hsplit()` creates a *view* on the data:

```
a = np.array(((1,2),(3,4)))
b, c = np.hsplit(a,2)
a[0][0]=99
```

gives for `b`:

```
array([[99],
       [ 3]])
```

I mean - what is the reasoning behind the implementation of this behaviour (which I find inconsistent and hard to remember): I accept that this happens because it's coded that way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the underlying ndarray data structure only has a single pointer to the start of its data's memory and then stride information about how to move through each dimension. If you concatenate two arrays, it won't know how to move from one memory location to the other. On the other hand, if you split an array into two arrays, each can easily store a pointer to the first element (which is somewhere inside the original array).

The basic C implementation is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L1747), and there is a good discussion at:

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/index.html#life-of-ndarray

Comment: I can't argue with either of these answers - makes perfect sense. It is a little scary never quite being sure whether you're dealing with a copy or a view, though...

Comment: One way to check if one array is potentially a view of another array is using `np.may_share_memory`

Answer (score 5):

NumPy generally tries to create views *whenever possible*, since memory copies are inefficient and can quite quickly eat up a lot of cycles.

`hsplit` splits the input array into multiple output arrays. The output arrays can each be views into a portion of the original parent array (since they are basically simple slices). Thus, for efficiency, NumPy creates views, instead of copies.

`hstack` combines two completely separate arrays into a single output array. The underlying array implementation cannot handle two separate data sources in a single array, so there is no way to share the data with the original. Thus, NumPy is forced to create a copy.